# Positioning image after animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one image (`#een`) to click on. When clicking on this this image it will `.animate` and will be reduced in size and another image (`#eeneen`) (and text) will appear. Unfortunately, `#eeneen` will not get to the upper top (original height of `#een`) , it sticks around somewhere.

How to get `#eeneen` to the same (original) height of `#een`? There is no `padding` active or something else..

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="jumbo">
    <div class="container">

        <div class="col">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <div class="een">
                    <img id="een" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/broadway/design.svg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                    <img id="eeneen" src="http://s.petrolicious.com/2015/vintage-friday/08-aug/paris/paris-6.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" style="display:none">

                    <div class="texteen" style="display:none">
                        <h1>Lorem ipsum.</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.jumbo {
}

.jumbo .col .een {
}

.jumbo .col .een img {
}

.jumbo .col .een #een {
    height: 170px;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-top: 60px;

}

.jumbo .col .een #eeneen {
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.jumbo .col .een .texteen h1{
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```js
var operator = '+=';
var operator1 = '+=';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".een").click(function() {
    $("#een").animate({left:operator + '-100',
                        top:operator + '+100',
                        width:operator1 + '-85',
                        height:operator1 + '-85',
                        });
        if(operator == '+='){operator = '-=';}
        else{operator = '+=';}
        if(operator1 == '+='){operator1 = '-=';}
        else{operator1 = '+=';}
    $("#eeneen").fadeToggle(300);
    $(".texteen").fadeToggle(600);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is "the original height"? Exactly? Could you make a screenshot with where the image should end up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `vertical-align: middle;` on `#eeneen` and give it the same `padding` and `margin` as you give `#een`.

CSS:

```
.jumbo .col .een #een {
    height: 170px;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-top: 60px;    
}

.jumbo .col .een #eeneen {
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqn512p2/1/)**

UPDATE:

If you want the image to go to the top of the page, you should remove the padding and margin on the second image.

CSS

```
.jumbo .col .een #een {
    height: 170px;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-top: 60px;    
}

.jumbo .col .een #eeneen {
    height: 200px;
    width: auto;
}
```

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvvjNY)**

**[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbbMwp)**

Comment: It is still sticked somewhere. This image `#een` has been lowered by `padding` and `margin`. But I want this `#eeneen` image higher than where the `#een` image is placed, i.e. `padding-top: 0px` and `margin-top: 0px` for `#eeneen` I guess.

Comment: @iJup Well that defines the top. Just remove the `vertical-align: middle` then. Should do the trick. Is this what you're after: http://jsfiddle.net/qqn512p2/2/ ?

Comment: I removed the `vertical-align: middle` in `.jumbo .col .een #eeneen` (like your post) but no result. Ps: the jsfiddle is not loading: it sticks at *initializing the awesome*.

Comment: @iJup That example still had the padding and margin in it to put it at the same height as the first image. Check the update, I also put the code in a codepen, see if you can open that.

Comment: Codepen seems to work right! But it still does not work out in my own code... I am working on this screenshots.

Comment: @iJup if it's working in Codepen, but not in your code then screenshots won't help. Try to re-create your problem in jsfiddle or codepen or link to live code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89283/discussion-between-ijup-and-timo).